# Put marker from Google Maps v3 in front of all others

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Can somebody help me put the current location in front of all others? I have read about MAX_ZINDEX and setZindex() but I cannot understand it. This is my code:

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
var image = "";
var currentplace = "Ohla Hotel";
var zInd = "";
if( name == currentplace ) {
    image = "../img/hotel_icon.png";
}
else {
    image = "../img/home_icon.png";
}
//alert();
var maxZindex = google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX;
if( name == currentplace ) {
    zInd = (maxZindex + 1);
}
var locationDescription = this.locationDescription;
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng,
    title:'pk:'+name,
    MAX_ZINDEX: zInd,
    icon: image
});
bounds.extend(latlng);
setMarker(map, marker, name, locationDescription);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`MAX_ZINDEX`is a constant, not an attribute of a marker.

The relevant MarkerOption is `zIndex`:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng,
    title:'pk:'+name,
    zIndex: zInd,
    icon: image
});
```

This sets the marker's `zIndex` attribute to the value you have calculated, which is one more than the API's maximum value.

Answer (score 3):

Most of your code makes sense, but your definition of the `MarkerOptions`[<sup>api-doc</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) object doesn't make sense. Try changing your marker creation code to this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng,
    title:'pk:'+name,
    zIndex: zInd,
    icon: image
});
```

Since you have already set the value of `zInd` higher than `google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX`, making this change should place the marker higher in the zIndex and thus above the other markers on the map.

Comment: i have already try it, ´zIndex: 999,´ and it not working at all give's me a error location, but if i do ´google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    marker.setZIndex(9999);
          ib.close();
          //ib.setContent($infoWindowContent[0]);
          ib.open(map, marker);´ it work just at hover what i need it a current location be on front.

Comment: What is the error that you get when you try to use the `MarkerOptions.zIndex` property?

Comment: that map doesn't locate at lat and lng

Comment: Do you mean the marker isn't located at the lat & lng? The map?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your English and figuring out exactly where the problem is located. I responded to the code you submitted in your question, but then you said the code in my answer you have already tried. If you want to update your question with your current code and the details about what you have tried, I will try to help. Otherwise, I am going to just have to admit that I can't figure out what you are saying. Maybe you can provide a link to your page or setup a jsFiddle?