# Google Maps z-Index value

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am creating a Google Maps Mashup and want to increase the z-index of one of the markers so that it is visible by some one zooms out.

http://startupsradar.com/

I want the Red Marker to be displayed above at all times.

Whats the default zIndex of the marker ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Put marker form Google Maps v3 in front of all others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068332/put-marker-form-google-maps-v3-in-front-of-all-others)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of zIndex for a marker can be up to maximum google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX. So if you want your marker to be above all, set the zIndex as (google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX + 1). e.g. 
**marker.setZIndex(google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX + 1);**

Comment: I don't understand, so if the maximum is google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX, then how can you set it to google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX + 1?  Wouldn't that be one above the maximum?

Comment: Search for `MAX_ZINDEX` on [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) *(I can't link directly link the exact place on the page)*. It says: `The maximum default z-index that the API will assign to a marker. You may set a higher z-index to bring a marker to the front.`